# bundle install--local vs bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have a doubt, instead of directly doing bundle install I:
1) First install the gem using gem install GemName in my laptop.
2) then write the gem-name in the Gemfile
3) Then do bundle install--local to install the gem in the desired app's gemfile.

Is this method fine or should I use bundle install instead of bundle install--local and the 1st step.
I want to know is there any difference in doing what I do and directly doing bundle install after writing the gem name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you should do such a thing? Just put in your Gemfile all the gems you need, then execute `bundle` or `bundle install` and you have done.

Comment: bundle install takes hell lot of time cause using virtual box to run ubuntu on windows 8.

Comment: bundler has to check if each gem in your Gemfile is currently installed in your system. If you keep Gemfile.lock saved, the command should be going faster.

Comment: I think the gemfile.lock is automatically saved during a project, we don't need to save it manually. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you need just to keep it saved. Anyway, bundle, when Gemfile.lock is present, is very fast to me (ruby 2.0.0p247 + gem 2.0.3), so I can't understand why you are worried about it.